# Label maker for Images using Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

Do anyone have a Svelte REPL for adding comments and tags on images. Similar to the ones using https://github.com/arturi/labelmaker. This is pretty good but I wanted to implement something similar using Svelte and wanted to know the best way to do it using Svelte constructs.